# How to make a standard field to not be required

Tags: community, account, required-field

I have a standard Account filed which is required and I need to make it to be not required in particular layout.

Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

Regards,

Dilyan

Answer (score 5):

Standard required fields are required. You can't make them optional. I have heard of people making Visualforce pages to set those fields to some value "behind the scenes", but they're still populated with some value. That's a lot of code to write just to add the convenience of a single field not being required.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, the only required "standard field" on Account by Salesforce is `Name`. This must be a custom field. You can make standard (non required) and non-standard fields optionally required by using Record Types.

Comment: It is the Account Name field which I need to make it to be not required. I'm using record types but still I find it difficult and impossible to make the Account Name standard field not required. Could you please advise or suggest a workaround on how to make the Account Name field not required?

Comment: Wow! The Name field is required for every record of every object whether standard or custom! That would be a challenging one for sure. I don't know that the system will allow that. You'd need to populate it with something for sure, even if it's a duplicate value that you conditionally render if the duplicate is detected. BTW, you'll need to bypass any dupe checks on that field too.

Comment: @crmprogdev re: name required for every record... except records that use an auto-number for their "name", such as cases and contracts, and custom objects that use auto-number name fields. However, as you've stated, Account Name is definitely one of those required fields. Just thought I'd point out the exceptions.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks Brian, good catch. It's the little details like that which can make all the difference in the world at times.;)

Answer (score 0):

Removing required fields from the detail page is possible via Dynamic forms on the record page.

We need to remove the existing detail page and add the fields one by one as we wish to show. When we save it'll show the warning stating that the required field is not added on the page; however, it'll not block the user. Plus with dynamic form we can show/hide the fields/buttons based on conditions.

Answer (score -2):

I used this scenario to change two required fields in 'Contact' object to not required. Steps - Go to setup - click object manager - find and choose contact - click fields and relationships - click the drop-down (extreme left side of the row) - click edit - Scroll down the page - In general options, uncheck 'Always require a value in this field in order to save a record' - click save. And it's DONE! :)

Comment: This question is about _standard_ fields. The process you're discussing does work, but only on _custom_ fields. You can't un-require standard fields.